# Coda: Automatically Clear JavaScript Console on page reload?

Tags: javascript, logging, console, coda

Is there any setting in Coda, or hackable solution, to get the JavaScript Console log to automatically clear itself after page reload?

I often stumble when I see old errors in the log, that doesn't still exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
console.clear();
```

If you want to erase all the previous logs and to show the fresh ones - put it on top of your JavaScript file.

Answer (score 3):

If you use jQuery try

```
$(function(){ console.clear(); });
```

Or try

```
window.onload = function(){ setTimeout("console.clear()",3000) }
```

Comment: Don't know why the window.load method works with the console.clear() in quotes.

Comment: it is same as setTimeout(() => { console.clear() },3000) or may be even setTimeout(console.clear, 3000)